# Sens a option select to mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I got a option select with 3 options in it(Open Closed and busy). 
Now I want to send my choosen option to my Mysql database.
I got this code.

Here is my function

```
function editStatus($pStatus, $id){
$id= (int) $id;
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET status = '$pStatus' WHERE id = '$id' ") or die (mysql_error());
}
```

Here i call my function

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if(isset($_POST['postcats'])) {
    editStatus($_POST['postcats'] , $_POST['$id']);
    header('location: posts.php'); 
}else{
    echo "Please set a post name";
    include('addpost.php');
}
}else{
header('location: addpost.php');
}
```

And here is my form

```
**                <tr>
                <TD><label for="postcats">Status</label></TD>
                <td><select name="postcats">
                       <option name="Open" value="Open">Open</option>
                       <option name="Busy" value="Busy">Busy</option>
                       <option name="Closed" value="Closed">Closed</option>
                    </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" /></td><td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo$_GET['id'];?>" /></td>
            </tr>**
```

I hope you guys know why it wont send it to my database..

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `editPost` function not `editStatus`

**NOTES**

- Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to catch errors.
- Add `die;` or `exit;` after `header("Location: ...");`
- You are vulnerable to sql injections because did not escape `$pStatus`.
- mysql_* functions are deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: My bad i've paste the wrong code in ny question. i've changed it to the right code. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it doesnt post to database, are you getting any errors from php or mysql? Also, you should not use deprecated mysql functions, use mysqli instead. And prepared statements to prevent SQL injection. Example below:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if(isset($_POST['status'])) {
    editStatus($_POST['status'], $_POST['id']);

    function editStatus($status, $id) {
      // Get the mysql connection
      $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'db');

      // Create a new prepared statement
      if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE posts SET status = ? WHERE id = ?")) {
        // Bind the parameters to replace the question marks on the query
        // In the correct order: si (String, Int)
        $stmt -> bind_param("si", $status, $id);
        // Execute the statement
        $stmt -> execute();
        // Close the statement
        $stmt -> close();
      }else {
        return $mysqli->error;
      }
      // Close the connection
      $mysqli -> close();
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```